# multiple latitude and longitude using Geo location in Gmap

Tags: google-maps

I want to fetch multiple Latitude and Longitude using Google Geo API.Actually I am using GMap module to render a map in which i am fetching business listing address from database but now i want to display google Listing also. example: http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=bars;near=chicago&radius=500&output=csv&key=' . $key it returns a single Latitude and Longitude but i want all latitude and longitude of bars type near chicago. Please help me on this.I would appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The geocoder geocodes postal addresses, and `bars;near=chicago` is not an address. The result you're getting is for `q=something,Chicago`, which is the nearest the geocoder can manage for your query. In fact it's not even finding the city: the result is for Chicago Avenue, Massapequa NY.

What you want to use is the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/). This is designed to return results of a certain class, based around a location.